# Is there any significant advantages to storing a value in a separate table?

Tags: sql-server

We have an Item table.  There's over a quarter million rows and over 200 fields in each row.  We need to add another field.  I created a table and linked it with a guid.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblItemInventoryClassx](
    RecordID uniqueidentifier not null,
    Code char not null,
    BusinessPotential VARCHAR(100) NOT null

    CONSTRAINT PK_tblItemInventoryClass PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(
        RecordID)
    WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

)   ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT tblItemInventoryClass VALUES(newid(), 'A', 'Maintain substantial inventory')
INSERT tblItemInventoryClass VALUES(newid(), 'B', 'Maintain minimum inventory')
INSERT tblItemInventoryClass VALUES(newid(), 'C', 'Tooling required to order')
INSERT tblItemInventoryClass VALUES(newid(), 'D', 'Sample required to order')
INSERT tblItemInventoryClass VALUES(newid(), 'E', 'Order parts as needed')
INSERT tblItemInventoryClass VALUES(newid(), 'F', 'Low demand, do not quote')
INSERT tblItemInventoryClass VALUES(newid(), 'Z', 'Unclassified')
```

Then add a field to link the main table

```
ALTER TABLE Item
    ADD RI_BusinessPotential identifier null
```

The guy doing the report wants to eliminate the table because he doesn't like guids and store the value directly in the table.  The table is so small I was wondering if he was right.  But then the table being so small I dont think it will impact the SQL much with an additional join.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're going to be referencing that GUID with that varchar(100)? If so, you're going to get poor performance when joining that (CONVERT_IMPLICIT warnings everywhere), try to keep the data types the same. Why not make the new table just have an ID field that is unique and have an FK on the main table to that, it doesn't have to be a GUID. Also, change that primary key to a clustered index, you'll thank me later.

Comment: you should consider field size if you have millions of records. Use smallest data type.

Comment: @joe Suggested reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization Also: What uses more space? An integer, a GUI, or a string of 30 characters? Then take the difference and multiple that for the number of rows.

Comment: @Rich: that was a typo.  I initially made it a uniqueidentifier but changed it while testing the alternative approach.  Using a separate table the new field is a guid.  Storing directly results in a varchar.

Comment: @Ricardo good point but off topic.  Consistency in database design is important.  If there are a hundred primary keys defined as guids I prefer not to have one table with an integer pkey.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to first think about the implication of storing the values of `BusinessPotential` directly in the item table in terms of business requirement, user experience, and data integrity.  In addition, a test to show whether a performance impact, if any, by join is significant and whether the cons outweighs the pros of having the extra table.  Your report guy has his own reason, and you should examine if his reason is valid, and whether the new design is superior or at least the best compromise.

One example for business requirement is editing/updating of a column value.  If this column will be editable by user in some kind of maintenance GUI for `item` table,  how would you know if the user-entry is correct? What kind of mechanism is available to detect or prevent unwanted value?  Will the system give user a pull-down list to choose from?  How is the pull-down menu created anyway? A foreign key constraint seems a much simpler and robust design, not to mention data entry would be much easier and less prone to error.

May I ask why you chose to have a `uniqueidentifier` as surrogate key?  As Matthew suggested, an INT surrogate key instead of `uniqueidentifier` is an option and will keep the row smaller, but in this case `code` alone seems sufficient.

Now, before testing the performance I'd suggest first cleaning up the table. Let's get rid of `RecordID`. Rename the `Code` column to `BusinessPotentialCode`, add that to the copy of `item` table, and create a foreign key constraint.  Remember to support the join with index, which is the key to optimal performance.

As for performance difference in join using varchar(100) or Char(1), I doubt there is a significant difference in your case, assuming the join is properly supported with index. But don't you think a predicate like

`BusinessPotentialCode IN ('A','B','C')`

seems better than

`BusinessPotentialDesc IN ('Maintain substantial inventory','Maintain minimum inventory','Tooling required to order')`?

A quick example of potential pitfall is a single quotation mark in the join column value.  That can make the above predicate very messy, very quickly.

Lastly, `BusinessPotential` seems very relevant to the demand or sales performance, meaning I expect it to get updated regularly. Assuming the average size of `BusinessPotential` is 30 bytes, let's consider 2 scenarios with 2 pseudo code.

`UPDATE SET Value_Old(char(30)) = Value_New(char(30))`

and

`UPDATE SET Value_old(char(1)) = Value_New(char(1))`

I think you know which one might run faster.

Comment: Thanks Kentaro for your thorough explanation.  To answer your questions I use a drop down so there is no issue of user entry, plus its easier and quicker for the users.  I prefer to use the foreign key design.  The reason I am using a guid is that is how the database is designed, consistency is important when dealing with large datasets.  Lastly this value will not get updated often, it will be used when purchasing to determine the best quantity discount.  You made me realize that one way is not significantly better than the other. I will make the report guy happy.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a good design practice (it is part of normalization) and unless your returning all the rows at once you will almost certainly not see any performance impact. There are many advantages and covering them all is a bit to board for SO but the biggest one I see every day as a programmer is that when you make an interface to update this information you can now make a list of each option instead of having to type it in. The list makes sure there is uniformity for each function instead of the variances in description that can happen when people type things in. It also allows you to pull records where items have specific `RI_BusinessPotential`.

EDIT: I missed the fact you where using `GUI`. I would suggest against this and just use an auto-incrementing PK of `INT` for even better performance and easier to write queries.

Comment: With 200 columns the person that created such ugly thing certainly does not like or understand normalization. I would say that with such a small list of values a GUI is not justified though; a simple int should suffice.

Comment: I am making the assumption he did not make the original table but I did miss the GUI part and updated my answer to reflect that he should be using an INT instead.

Comment: Yes, I get it. I agree with what you say. I was also referring to whoever was the crazy person that built a 200 column table,

Comment: @Ricardo If you ever work on a large database, especially an ERP system, you will find large structures can and do normally exist.  Good thing I didnt tell you there were almost 700 tables.  Maybe

Comment: @Matthew: Nothing is going to be typed in, it will all be selected from a combobox.  I would prefer to use the separate table but my boss is making the report and wants to stuff the value right into the main table.  I was hoping to find something to help me persuade him otherwise but SO wasnt able to provide me any ammo for my argument, oh well.

Comment: SO it not really going to be the right place to get ammo like that as it would be to board of a question for SO. If you tell him that best practice is to have the second table which will allow for easier development, update, and maculation of the and he does not care then you, in my experience, will not get anywhere.

Comment: @Joe 700 tables sounds ugly but not as bad as 200 columns, ERP or not, however often you see it, this is no logical argument for good design. That is only argument to incur into the same mistakes the people around us. Anyways, I have no access to your schema so this argument is moot, however cringing the idea of 200 columns and 700 tables... send the original creators to DB normalization training camp. =(

Comment: @Ricardo Here is an excerpt from wikipedia about 1NF "A relation is in first normal form if and only if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic (indivisible) values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain."  To reduce the number of columns is called denormalization, the complete opposite of what you said.

Comment: @joe i am sorry but you are incorrectly understanding normalization. From Wikipedia "Database Normalization": Normalization involves decomposing a table into less redundant (and smaller) tables without losing information, and then linking the data back together by defining foreign keys in the old table referencing the primary keys of the new ones. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @Ricardo the key words are "less redundant."  Splitting up a table does not necessarily make anything "less redundant" and infact, will increase redundancy by requiring (unnecessarily) a key to link tables together.  That last fact is insignificant, but what is significant, would be chopping up a table that, according to your definition fails to provide normalization but does increase application complexity and also increase query execution time is undesirable.  Basically making blind assumptions without any knowledge the way the real world works leads to errors.